# where condition in include, how?

Tags: linq, repository, dbcontext, objectcontext

The code below is not working. I am getting exception "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties."
What im doing wrong

```
    public static MyEntity GetData(this IQueryable<MyEntity> source, int id, int year)
    {
        return source.Where(x => x.ID == id)
            .Include(x => x.Childrens1)
            .Include(x => x.Childrens2.where(y => y.Year == year))
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is not supported into Include expression, you only can use select, even nested. move where out of include

```
public static MyEntity GetData(this IQueryable<MyEntity> source, int id, int year)
{
    return source
        .Include(x => x.Childrens1)
        .Include(x => x.Childrens2)
        .Where(x => x.ID == id && x.Childrens2.Any(y => y.Year == year))
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Now, you also can unify where or filter inside FirstOrDefault

Comment: @glez I don't think that's correct, the year property is on Children2 object, and Childrens2 is collection.